# pcl 1.7 install on groovy

Tags: pcl, catkin, ros-groovy, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to install the pcl1.7 from https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git (the groovy-unstable-devel) in ubuntu 12.04 64 bits with ROS Groovy.

I has still using the rosbuild system, but it appears that the pcl git is allready made for catkin. So i created a catkin workspace as the the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment), clone the git to the src dir, and making catkin_make i get this:

```
Base path: /home/joao/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/joao/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/joao/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/joao/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/joao/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/joao/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/joao/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/joao/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/joao/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/joao/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/joao/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/joao/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/joao/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - pcl (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - pcl_ros
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:88 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

What should i do? I've read the tutorials and it didn't give me a answer.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66169/pcl-1.7-install-on-groovy/) by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

" and catkin cannot build a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation."
-> use catkin_make_isolated

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-25**:
Thanks that was really helpful